# How do I insert records into two tables when the second table references the primary key in the first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm trying to insert records into two tables. The second table has a column that references the Primary Key of the first table. How can I insert into both using one script? Should I use scope_identity and a do an insert one after the other or is there a more efficient way?

First table columns:

```
OrgUnitAttributeID (PK)
OrgUnitID
AttributeTypeID
AttributeValue
CreatedByUserID
CreatedDateUTC
UpdatedByUserID
UpdatedDateUTC
IsActive
```

Second table columns:

```
DisplayMessageAttributeID
DisplayMessageTypeID
OrgUnitAttributeID (PK that's created in the first table)
CreatedDateUTC
```

Comment: How about you try it? Does it work? There's your answer!

Comment: use the OUTPUT values clause rather than scope_identity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #callback ([ID] INT);

INSERT INTO First.Table (Columns)
OUTPUT inserted.OrgUnitAttributeID 
INTO #callback ([ID])
SELECT *
FROM Data.Source;

INSERT INTO Second.Table (columns)
SELECT *
FROM Other.DataSource
    JOIN #callback ON (Whatever the unique key is);
```

This is the general pattern. You'll have to tweak the names and column lists. In addition, you will need to add a second column to the callback temp table to link the newly generated ID to a unique key field on the second table. Best of luck.